# Displaying data from a database table based on id of user logged in

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to get certain information from a database according to the user that's logged in. Right now I can get information from the columns and rows but its not user specific. Can I use a `$_SESSION`? Would that work in the `$query`?

PHP:

```
$query = "SELECT * ".
"FROM leavetable, users ".
"WHERE leavetable.users_id = users.id ";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo ' <tr> ';
    echo ' <td> ';
    echo $row['id'];
    echo ' <td> ';
    echo $row['hours'];
    echo ' <td> ';
    echo $row['email'];
    echo ' <td> ';
    echo $row['username'];
    echo ' <td> ';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but never build your SQL queries like suggested by Mr Shahnewaz's answer. This kind of approach is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, I'd suggest you to take some time to [read about them](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) and experiment.

The proper way to perform a parameterized query is by using a prepared statement:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM leavetable WHERE leavetable.users_id = :id');
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $_SESSION['user_id']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch();
```

The key point to keep in mind is that the query string passed to the `prepare` method must be a plain hardcoded string. You can use named placeholers (:whatever) where needed, as shown in the example.

By the way, in this example `$dbh` would be an instance of the [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) class, which you [might consider](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) using instead of the old mysql_* functions.